# Reading PE files EntryPointAdress using c#

Tags: c#, portable-executable, entry-point

Is there a good way to read PE files entrypoint? I found some codes in the following line http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=572

My code is:

```
PeHeaderReader reader = new PeHeaderReader("c:\\testfile.exe");
if (reader.Is32BitHeader)
{
   long EntryPoint = reader.OptionalHeader32.AddressOfEntryPoint;
}
```

The problem is the entrypoint is not accurate?

Comment: What do you mean that it's not accurate? What do you want to do with the address you get?

Comment: I tried to get the entrypoint of sample file test.exe .... the resulted entrypoint in my app is: 5092 but the value in other app is 2020

Comment: What other app is this? Are you sure you are comparing the same things? And, again, why do you need this value?

Comment: i'm developing tool to detect viruses . and i need this value to let my tool to get virus entrypoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved the probelm by converting the EntryPoint(RVA) to FileOffest . Thanks